# HERE Routing API - Matrix/Multiple arrival times?

Tags: here-api, herepy

Update: I have switched to HERE Routing API because I was told that it would be faster. I am trying to use HerePy to get a routing matrix, but I am getting the following error message:

AttributeError: 'RoutingApi' object has no attribute 'matrix'

Regardless of whether I find out how to move past this error, it's also not clear whether this API could accept multiple departure times (Each of my origins has its own departure time.). I have a feeling I will also run into the matrix size issue again. Does anyone know how to fix this error and/or know more about what I'm able to do? I had a phone call with someone from the sales department, but they didn't know the answers to these questions.

---

Original Question: I am trying to use the Google Maps Distance Matrix API. I have an array or origins, an array of destinations, and then an array of arrival times. Each destination has its own arrival time. From what I have read in the documentation, it is not clear whether I can use an array of arrival times, or just one arrival time per request. Does anyone know?

I suppose if I can only do one arrival time per request, then I would just group together the destinations with the same arrival times into one request. I will need to do multiple requests anyway due to the 100 maximum of elements/25 maximum of origins or destinations per request.

Thanks!

Comment: There is only one [arrival time in the request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview#request-parameters), it is only applicable to transit directions.

Comment: Distance Matrix API is billed by matrix element (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing#distance-matrix), so there is no additional cost in sending many requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Matrix Routing API offered by Here API.

The Matrix Routing service is an HTTP JSON API that calculates routing matrices, travel times and/or distances, of up to 10,000 origins and 10,000 destinations. A routing matrix is a matrix with rows labeled by origins and columns by destinations. Each entry of the matrix is the travel time or distance from the origin to the destination.

For more information , please do visit to the following [link](http://The%20Matrix%20Routing%20service%20is%20an%20HTTP%20JSON%20API%20that%20calculates%20routing%20matrices,%20travel%20times%20and/or%20distances,%20of%20up%20to%2010,000%20origins%20and%2010,000%20destinations.%20A%20routing%20matrix%20is%20a%20matrix%20with%20rows%20labeled%20by%20origins%20and%20columns%20by%20destinations.%20Each%20entry%20of%20the%20matrix%20is%20the%20travel%20time%20or%20distance%20from%20the%20origin%20to%20the%20destination.)